# Page not found (404) django

Tags: python, django

Can anyone help me with this issue. When I try to access I get the following error.

Request Method: GET
Request URL:
Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^myproject/$ [name='home']
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
#url(r'^$', 'myproject.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^booking/$', 'booking.views.home', name ='home'),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
#..

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render("Hello, guesthouse!!")
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'booking',
)
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from booking.models import Bookings


# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Bookings)
```

Thank you,
Rads

Answer (score 3):

You are getting 404 because 'home' doesn't exist in views.py or by mistake, you have named the view wrong.

below i have changed the name of view to 'home' that matches the view specified in your urls.py

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    """
      home view
    """
    return render("Hello, guesthouse!!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have a `home` function in `booking.views`.

Expanded answer: Each URL spec has a couple of parts that tell Django how to route the request. In your post you have:

`url(r'^booking/$', 'booking.views.home', name ='home'),`

In order for the mapping to work you need to have the function:

`booking.views.home`

You have three options here, the first is to implement another view function, the second is that you can rename `booking.views.index` to `booking.views.home`, and the third is that you can change the url spec to the following:

`url(r'^booking/$', 'booking.views.index', name ='home'),`

All three of these options assume that you have a directory structure like:

```
|-<project_root_dir>
|   |
|   |- <project>
|   |- booking
|   |     |- <other files>
|   |     |- views.py
```

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for the suggestion. What sort of home function are you referring to?

Comment: Take a look at the revised answer

Comment: Hi John, Thank you very much for the suggestions. I followed your instructions. Still stuck with the same error :( Not sure yet how to resolve it. Any suggestions on it? Thank you for your time. Regards, Rads

Comment: What is the URL you're providing the browser?

Comment: When I use# for #url(r'^booking/$', 'booking.views.index', name ='home'), I can access the admin page wherein, I can see booking and can add details from there but when I try to access without # I still have an issue accessing it. Thank you for your time John.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in urls.py. Your last pattern is incorrect. I think it should be

```
url(r'^booking/$', 'booking.views.index'),
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the suggestion it didn't work earlier with 'booking.views.index' so I posted the url with 'booking.views.home'.

Comment: I tried with this url earlier it didn't work. url(r'^booking/$', 'booking.views.index')

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you command. Correct me if I'm wrong -- you have a module views.py located within the 'booking' app directory. Within that module is a function 'index()'. If that is the case, then you need to map your url() pattern to specifically invoke that function. If that is not working, then look to your directory/module layout. Something else is not right.

Comment: myproject                                                             |-booking                                                               --init.py, admin.py, models.py,tests.py,views.py,urls.py                                                                                                                                                                          |-myproject                                                           ----init.py,settings.py,urls.py, wsgi.py

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404

from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

from booking.models import *

# Create your views here.
def index(request):     
 return render("Hello guesthouse!!")